# facing issues while creating REGEX expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create regex experssion which can replace only `','` only at the end or start of the string with `''`

e.g.

```
Input -  Sunday,Monday        Output - Sunday,Monday
Input -  Sunday,              Output - Sunday
Input -  ,Monday              Output - Monday
```

Comment: Show us your code, what have you tried so far

Comment: I tried following regex [^a-zA-Z0-9\,]

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What programming language (or tool) do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `^`, and `$` to match only at the beginning or at the end:

```
/^,|,$/
```

Following is Javascript example:

```
'Sunday,Monday'.replace(/^,|,$/g, '') // => "Sunday,Monday"
'Sunday,'.replace(/^,|,$/g, '')       // => "Sunday"
',Monday'.replace(/^,|,$/g, '')       // => "Monday"
```